# github conflict when someone manually ftp files remote

Tags: github

Some one manually upload files directly to web server, as a result github is not same as the physical file contents in production.

And there are many files, I m afraid.

1 - Howto refresh the github master, so that it will show correct contents of the production server.

2 - And howto refresh my local dev according the refreshed github master in step 1?

Comment: I think the best solution is to stop manually uploading files directly to the live server.  Use GitHub as the gate keeper.  Everything goes through there first before deployment.

Comment: But someone already done this, any idea how to rescue - i know i will not allow anyone to manually upload later

Comment: You might have to manually check this, perhaps with the aid of a good bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow copy all the files from the web server to your local repo: Git will detect the new/modified/deleted files in your local repo after that copy.

Once that synchronization is done in your local repo, add, commit and push to GitHub.